# Cumulative mass & mass distribution of a disc galaxy

Tags: mass, galaxies

Hernquist has a great formula to represent the cumulative mass of a spherical galaxy (8):

http://star-www.st-and.ac.uk/~hz4/contempastro/hqm.pdf

1) Is there any simple formula for disc shaped galaxy in terms of M(r)?
2) And if so what is the mass distribution (derivative)?

For reference, all of the known spherical models are described here: http://www.astro.sunysb.edu/lattimer/AST346/part4.pdf

- Power Law
- Hernquist
- Jaffe
- Plummer
- Navarro-Frenk-White

Comment: This is just speculation, but [Hernquist's original derivation](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1990ApJ...356..359H) was motivated by de Vaucouleurs's law, which is an intensity function for elliptical galaxies. De Vaucouleurs's law is a special case of Sérsic's law ($n=4$), so if you were to choose a different value for $n$ ($1$ for discs), you would arrive at an analogous version for disc galaxies. You could then write up an analogous version of Hernquist's result.

Comment: Do you mean all gravitating mass?

Comment: Ok thanks.  I can see Sersic's law in terms of intensity (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sersic_profile) but how do I convert that in terms of M(r)?

Comment: M(r) is the mass within a given radius

Comment: In which case it is completely dominated by the dark halo. Einasto profile or Navarro Frenk & White profile.

Comment: I just wish to consider baryonic matter

Comment: I see NFW (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navarro%E2%80%93Frenk%E2%80%93White_profile) which fits the Milky Way but includes the dark matter halo as well.  Thanks anyways I really appreciate.